# Firmata over nRF24

Tags: c#, serial-port, arduino, spi, firmata

I'm having some technical problems... I'm trying to use Firmata for arduino but over nrf24, not over Serial interface. I have tested nRF24 communication and it's fine. I have also tested Firmata over Serial and it works.

Base device is simple "serial relay". When it has data available on Serial, read it and send it over [nRF24 network](http://maniacbug.github.com/RF24Network/index.html). If there is data available from network, read it and send it through Serial.

Node device is a bit complex. It has custom [Standard Firmata](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Firmata) where I have just added write and read override.

[image: Diagram]

Read override id handeled in `loop` method in this way:

```
while(Firmata.available())
    Firmata.processInput();

// Handle network data and send it to Firmata process method
while(network.available()) {
    RF24NetworkHeader header;
    uint8_t data;
    network.read(header, &data, sizeof(uint8_t));
    Serial.print(data, DEC); Serial.print(" ");
    Firmata.processInputOverride(data);
    BlinkOnBoard(50);
}

currentMillis = millis();
```

Firmata `processInputOverrride` is little changed method of `processInput` where `processInput` reads data directly from `FirmataSerial`, and in this method we pass data down to method from network. This was tested and it should work fine.

Write method is overloaded in a different way. In `Firmata.cpp` I have added an method pointer that can be set to a custom method and used to send data using that custom method. I have then added custom method call after each of the `FirmataSerial.write()` call:

```
Firmata.h
...
size_t (*firmataSerialWriteOverride)(uint8_t);
...

void FirmataClass::printVersion(void) {
  FirmataSerial.write(REPORT_VERSION);
  FirmataSerial.write(FIRMATA_MAJOR_VERSION);
  FirmataSerial.write(FIRMATA_MINOR_VERSION);
  Firmata.firmataSerialWriteOverride(REPORT_VERSION);
  Firmata.firmataSerialWriteOverride(FIRMATA_MAJOR_VERSION);
  Firmata.firmataSerialWriteOverride(FIRMATA_MINOR_VERSION);
}
```

I have then set the overrided write method to a custom method that just writes byte to network instead of `Serial`.

```
size_t ssignal(uint8_t data) {
    RF24NetworkHeader header(BaseDevice);
    network.write(header, &data, sizeof(uint8_t));
}

void setup() {
...
Firmata.firmataSerialWriteOverride = ssignal;
...
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine, it's just that some data seems to be inverted or something. I'm using sharpduino (C#) to do some simple digital pin toggle. Here's how output looks like: (< came from BASE, > sent to BASE)

```
> 208 0
> 209 0
...
> 223 0
> 249
< 4 2 249 
and here communication stops...
```

That last line came inverted. So i tough that I only need to invert received bytes. And it worked for that first command. But then something happens and communication stops again.

```
> 208 0
> 209 0
...
> 223 0
> 249 // Report firmware version request
< 249 2 4
> 240 121 247 // 240 is sysex begin and 247 is systex end
< 240 121
< 101 0 67 0 0 1 69 0 118
< 117 0 115 0
< 0 70 0 105 0 116 0 111 0 109
< 0 97 0
< 0 109
< 116 0 97 0 247
> 240 107 247
```

So what could be the problem here? It seems that communication with Firmata works but something isn't right...

**-- EDIT --**

I solved that issue. The problem was that I didn't see `Serial.write()` calls in sysex callback. Now that that is solved, I came up to another problem... All stages pass right (I guess) and then I dont get any response from Node when I request pin states

```
...
< f0 6a 7f 7f 7f ... 7f 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f f7 // analog mapping
> f0 6d 0 f7 // sysex request pin 0 state and value
> f0 6d 1 f7 
> f0 6d 2 f7
...
> f0 6d 45 f7
// And I wait for response...
```

There is no response. Any ideas why would that happen? Node receive all messages correctly and code for handling pin states exist.